# Every Cauchy sequence converges

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, cauchy-sequences

***SENTENCE***:

The p-adic numbers are complete with respect to the p-norm, ie every Cauchy sequence converges.

**PROOF**:

Let $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy-sequence in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

We want to show that, without loss of generality, we can suppose that $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.Let the set $\{ |x_i|_p | i \in \mathbb{N}\} \subset \mathbb{R}$. We suppose that it is upper bounded. If not, there are $\forall m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$ two indices $i,j \geq N$ with $|x_i|_p> |x_j|_p \geq p^m$.

From the sentence: For $|x|_p \neq |y|_p$, it stands that $|x+y|_p=\max \{|x|_p, |y|_p \} $, we have that $|x_i-x_j|_p=|x_i|_p>p^m$. This is not possible for a Cauchy-sequence.

Now, we pick $m \in \mathbb{N}$ with $p^m \geq \max \{ |x_i|_p | i \in \mathbb{N}_0 \}$. Then, $(p^m x_i)_i$ is a Cauchy-sequence with $|p^mx_i|_p \leq 1 \Rightarrow p^mx_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. It converges exactly then, when $(x_i)_i$ converges.

So, we just need to consider a Cauchy-sequence $(x_i)_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. We want to show that it converges and to determine its limit $z \in \mathbb{Z}_p$. For each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we pick a $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$, so that:

$$|x_i-x_j|_p<p^{-k} ,\text{ for } i,j \geq N_k$$

We can suppose, that $N_k$ is an increasing sequence.The above inequality is equivalent to $v_p(x_i-x_j)>k$ or $x_i-x_j \in p^{k+1} \mathbb{Z}_p$. So, we find a $z_k \in \mathbb{Z}$, such that:

$$z_k \equiv x_i \equiv x_i \mod p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z}_p, \text{ for } i,j \geq N_k$$

Because of $N_{k+1} \geq N_k$, it stands that:
$$z_{k+1} \equiv x_{N_{k+1}} \equiv x_{N_k} \equiv z_k \mod p^{k+1} \mathbb{Z}_p$$

ie. $z=(\overline{z_k})_k \in \Pi \mathbb{Z}/p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z}$ is an element from $\mathbb{Z}_p$. Also, for $i \geq N_k$, it stands that:
$$x_i \equiv z_k \equiv \ \mod p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z}_p \Rightarrow |x_i-z|_p<p^{-p}$$

so $x_i$ converges to $z$.

Could you explain me step by step the above proof?

[image]

Comment: How is $\mathbb Q_p$ defined if not as the *completion* of $\mathbb Q$ under $|\cdot |_p$? In which case the theorem just follows from the fact that completions are complete ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is defined like that:

$$\mathbb{Q}_p=\{ \frac{r}{s}| r,s \in \mathbb{Z}_p, s \neq 0 \}$$

Comment: @evinda: If you define $\mathbb{Q}_p=\{ \frac{r}{s}| r,s \in \mathbb{Z}_p, s \neq 0 \},$ then what is your definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p?$ If it is the completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ with respect to the maximal ideal $(p),$ then the last part of the above proof is redundant. But in the proof we have the following condition: $|p^mx_i|_p \leq 1 \Rightarrow p^mx_i \in \mathbb{Z}_p.$ It's almost looks like $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is defined as $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}_p : |x|_p \leq 1 \}.$ It's little bit of confusing for me. May be you can give the reference of this post.

Comment: @Krish Yes, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is defined as $\{ x \in \mathbb{Q}_p: |x|_p \leq 1 \}$. The proof is from a german book(Elementare und algebraische Zahlentheorie)..

Comment: So, $\mathbb Q_p$ is defined in terms of $\mathbb Z_p$ and $\mathbb Z_p$ is defined in terms of $\mathbb Q_p$? I think you are having German trouble.

Comment: I assume that is Müller-Stach, Piontkowski, ''Elementare und algebraische Zahlentheorie'', Springer. I don't have it available but I doubt that they use circular definitions. Please check.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen It is exactly this proof, I just translated it.. Do you want to see the original? Shall I send a picture of it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There is also an other definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, this one:

$$\mathbb{Z}_p=\{ (\overline{x_k}) \in \Pi_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/p^{k+1} \mathbb{Z} | x_{k+1} \equiv x_k \mod{p^{k+1}}\}$$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I added a picture of the original proof.

Comment: That's all we were asking - how is $\mathbb Z_p$ defined. It's hard to prove some metric space is complete until you give a definition. @evinda

Comment: Ok.. I wrote the other definition at a previous comment..